# Can oxidizing agents act as comburents?

Tags: redox, combustion

Comburent, to the best of my knowledge, refer to substances that catalyze combustion reactions without reacting itself or being flammable independently, such as potassium chromate. How would oxidizing agents assist combustion reactions?

Comment: Well, potassium chromate is a useful oxidizing agent, so you may have already answered your title question.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I meant to say that potassium chromate is a strong oxidizer, I didn't know it was a comburent. Also, I don't understand how or why.

Comment: Comburent would seem to include materials which are themselves combustible. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comburent